# SVG Path Element

Tags: svg

I know what "c0.88,0.88,2.75,1.82,5.25,1.75" means. But I don't know what "c8.62-0.25,20-2.12,29.5-4.25" means, especially the '-' symbol in it.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-0.25 means negative coordinate